# PHP - reset namespace to global

Tags: php, namespaces

I want to access global `namespace` functions from within a page that has had a `namespace` declared, without having to go through the hassle of adding a `\` before every function.

How can I reset back to the global namespace?

**Example:**

```
<?php
namespace Stupid\Namespace;
$page = new page;

function zipUp() {
  $zip = new ZipArchive();
  //doesn't matter what the rest of this function is,
  //because it will already have had a fatal error
  //unless I add a leading \, like new \ZipArchive();
}
```

Ideally, I just want to declare the global namespace, like I can with other namespaces, just for this function:

```
function zipUp() {
  namespace \; \\ OR namespace global; etc.
  $zip = new ZipArchive();
}
```

The only method that works (that I can find) is to wrap the function in braces (`namespace { function foo(){...} }`, but then I have to wrap everything that uses the main namespace in braces too, which is not feasible.

Hopefully I'm being stupid and missing something obvious, or there's a good reason why something that should be so basic isn't possible, but I can't seem to find any evidence of either of these reasons.

Comment: add `use \ZipArchive;` after the namespace declaration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just import the class using [`use`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)

Example:

```
<?php
namespace Stupid\Namespace;
use \zipArchive;
//use \zipArchive as zipArch; (You could use the class as a custom shorthand to interact with that class if you want)

$page = new page;

function zipUp() {
  $zip = new ZipArchive();
  //new zipArchive() should not throw a fatal exception
}
```

Comment: +1 because it does seem like it would help, from my example.  However, whilst I've only used a single function for an example, this particular function uses `RecursiveIteratorIterator`, `RecursiveDirectoryIterator`, and several other global functions, which is why I want to just write a single `namespace` declaration.  Otherwise, I could list each function with `use` statements, or prefix them with `\\`, but that's not what I want to do.

Comment: @JoeP I don't really know how you could tell your script to load things without declaring exactly what those things are, you may be out of luck on what you want. That said, you could probably make an array of all the things you want to load and use a loop to include them with `use`, but I'm not really sure if that's what you want either. Maybe I'm not fully understanding what you mean by "write a single `namespace` declaration? The server has to know which namespace to load them from.

Comment: Without declaring a namespace at all, the function will run without problems.  However, I need to declare the namespace to use `$page`, for example.  If it works without declaring a namespace, then there surely must be a way to "unset" the namespace to return to the `global` or default namespace.

Comment: @JoeP I do not think there is a way to do that, but what if you just reversed the roles? Remove the namespace declaration and try to do `use Stupid\Namespace`. It may work? I'm not sure of your setup or anthing, but if not you may be out of luck :(

Comment: It's looking like there isn't a way, which seems pretty daft.  I'm reluctant to accept your answer, since it's not actually what I wanted, but it does work and might actually be the only other way of avoiding the need to prefix the function calls with a `\\` individually, so it would be harsh not to.  I'll leave it temporarily, and accept it if no better solution surfaces.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @JoeP Thank you! Sorry you didn't find what you wanted